# fill out field in update secton in Angular/Firestore CRUD

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

What I'm asking for is pretty simple but I just can't work it out or find the solution for Firestore.

I'm specifically struggling with displaying the current field entry in the form based on the id sent in the url. I also don't think it's getting the 'where' condition properly either.

i.e. Wen you come to edit the entry I'm trying to get it to display the 'domain' value in its field for editing based on the id sent in the url.

ts file:

```
form = new FormGroup({
    domain: new FormControl(""),
  });

  constructor(
    private aptService: DomainService,
    private actRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    public authService: AuthenticationService,
    public fireStore: AngularFirestore
  ) {
    this.id = this.actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    const docRef = this.fireStore.collection("qm-domain", (ref) =>
      ref.where("id", "==", this.id)
    );
    docRef.snapshotChanges().subscribe((res) => {
      this.form.setValue(res);
    })
  }
```

html file:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="updateForm()">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label position="floating">Domain</ion-label>
        <ion-input formControlName="domain" type="text" required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
          <ion-button type="submit" color="primary" shape="full" expand="block">Update Domain</ion-button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

For anyone else that's having the same issue, here's what I've done:

```
    form = new FormGroup({
    domain: new FormControl(""),
  });

  constructor(
    private aptService: DomainService,
    private actRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    public fb: FormBuilder,
    public authService: AuthenticationService,
    public fireStore: AngularFirestore
  ) {
    this.id = this.actRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    // get the record based on this.id
    const docRef = this.fireStore
      .collection("qm-domain")
      .doc(this.id)
      .snapshotChanges();
    // put it in the form
    docRef.subscribe((res) => {
      this.form.setValue(res.payload.data());
      console.log(res.payload.data());
    });
  }
```